# handlebars-js - more complex json api

Tags: json, handlebars.js

I hit the problem with displaying json data properly using handlebars.js template. My template currently looks like this:

```
    <div id="films"></div>

    <script type="text/handlebars-template" id="handlebars-template">
        {{#films}}
        <div>
          <img href="{{id}}" alt="poster">
          <p>{{title}}</p>
        </div>
        {{/films}}
    </script>
```

Reaching first array with film titles and poster ids go fine but what I obviously need is to put urls in images src to display film posters.

JS is following:

```
    var $placeHolder = $("#films");
    var handlebarsTemplate = $("#handlebars-template").html();
    var templateCompile = Handlebars.compile(handlebarsTemplate);
    var data = {
    "films" : [
       {"id" : 17, "posterId" : 7039523, "title" : "Blues Brothers (1980)"},
       {"id" : 702, "posterId" : 6900923, "title" : "Seven (1995)"},
    ],
    "posters": [
        {"id" : 7039523, "url" : "http://1.fwcdn.pl/po/00/17/17/7581123.6.jpg"},
        {"id" : 6900923, "url" : "http://1.fwcdn.pl/po/07/02/702/6967799.6.jpg"},
     ],
   },

   $placeHolder.html(templateCompile(data));
},
```

So how can I reach two different data arrays in my template to display both film titles and posters based on url? Is it necessary to refer to posterID? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Massage the data into a form that is easier to handle.

For example (click "Run code snippet" below):

```js
var filmTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#films-template").html());

var rawData = {
    "films" : [
           {"id" : 17, "posterId" : 7039523, "title" : "Blues Brothers (1980)"},
           {"id" : 702, "posterId" : 6900923, "title" : "Seven (1995)"},
    ],
    "posters": [
            {"id" : 7039523, "url" : "http://1.fwcdn.pl/po/00/17/17/7581123.6.jpg"},
            {"id" : 6900923, "url" : "http://1.fwcdn.pl/po/07/02/702/6967799.6.jpg"},
        ],
    };


var films = rawData.films.map(function (filmInfo) {
    return $.extend({}, filmInfo, {
        poster: rawData.posters.find(function (p) {
            return p.id === filmInfo.posterId;
        })
    });
});
    
$("#films").html(filmTemplate(films));
$("#data").text(JSON.stringify(films, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<pre id="data" style="float: right; font-size: 50%;"></pre>
<div id="films"></div>

<script type="text/handlebars-template" id="films-template">
    {{#each this}}
    <div>
      <img alt="poster" src="{{poster.url}}">
      <p>{{title}}</p>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: Haha, this is so easy to find out that I am the beginner? Gonna remember ;)